# React state is changing but a part of previous data still show up top of the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Example: If there are 2 old data and the new data is just 1 table showing up 1 old and 1 new data.
I put a log inside map function everything working as expected but not seeing true

Here is my code:

```
   <Table hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Personel</th>
                        <th>Verdiği Servis Hizmeti Sayısı</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    { this.state.reportDetails.length > 0 ? this.state.reportDetails.map((reportDetail) => {
                        return (
                        <tr key={reportDetail.employeeId}>
                            <td>{reportDetail.employee}</td>
                            <td>{reportDetail.totalQuantityOfHandledService}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                    })
                    : <h3 className="text-center mt-5">Belirtilen kriterlere göre kayıt bulunamadı!</h3>}
                </tbody>
                
            </Table>
```

---

this part of the code runnig when i change a selectbox

```
getReport(id) {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        let url = "/api/reports/GetReportForEmployee?employeeId=" + id;
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then(async (response) => {
                const result = await response.json();

                if (!response.ok) {
                    const error = result;
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }
                
                await this.setState(() =>  {return {reportDetails: result.data}});
                

            })
            .catch((responseError) => {
                if (responseError.Message == "Token Bulunamadı!") {
                    this.CreateTokenByRefreshToken();
                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the setState without "await", and passing the new value without calling a function:

```
this.setState({reportDetails: result.data});
```

Comment: unfortunately still same

Comment: Okay. React probably think your object is the same, so it doesn't re-render. Try to set a new array to the state:
this.setState({reportDetails: ...result.data});

Comment: When I write exactly like this [ this.setState({reportDetails: ...result.data}); ], I encounter an error: Expression expected.ts(1109)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState` won't return a `Promise`. I recommend you change some part of your code:

```
 fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
   }
 })
 .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("request failed: ");
    }
  }) //--> call json() in a separate then block
 .then(result) => {
     this.setState({reportDetails: result.data});
  })
  .catch((responseError) => {
      if (responseError.Message == "Token Bulunamadı!") {
        this.CreateTokenByRefreshToken();
      }
  })
```

Comment: I tried this but when the code is like this no data is listed

Comment: Did you check that second then block is executed. If it is not, maybe response.ok is false and you are getting some error. I updated my answer